# Accessing "AllocatedFrom" compartment from Rhapsody java api

Tags: java, uml, allocation, rhapsody

I need to customise a generic Internal block diagram to show customer specific variants. A simple tag based discrimination mechanism is used to suppress non relevant flows and allocated operations.

I have written a Java plug-in to iterate over the IBD’s encapsulated `IRPGraphElements`, examining their associated type and acting appropriately.

Manipulation of the flows is working fine, but I am having a lot of problems with the allocated operations – in summary I have 2 problems…

1. I cannot get a handle to the “AllocatedFrom” compartment
2. And therefore I cannot get to the IRPCollection containing the references to the actual operations.

#### Problem 1.

I have examined both the Rhapsody Java api documentation (!!!) and Java objects at runtime trying to discover the appropriate method(s) to invoke.

As it is a purely presentational issue (I do not want to suppress underlying allocations between model elements) I guess it is some kind of graphical property & I had thought it would be `ObjectModelGe` oriented.

I have looked at the properties mentioned in the Diagram package of the SysML profile.

Within `General::Graphics` I can see the `AdditionalCompartments` property mentions (amongst other things) `AllocatedFrom`

However within `ObjectModelGe::Object` I see that the `Compartments` property only mentions `Operation` – do I need to add `AllocatedFrom` to this property?

#### Problem 2.

Even if I get access to the compartment I am not sure what methods will be available to access the collection – there appears no interface defined for compartments. Looking in the *.sbs* file I can see that it is of type `IRPYRawContainer` but I cannot find any documentation on this.